# repositioning tikz-pins in pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgf-pie, pie

I only want to know if anyone has an idea on how to reposition the tikz-pin in a way that they look like the pins in the example picture without creating extra nodes? this is my code so far:
P.S.: if it is not possible is there any way to position the pins nearer to the pie chart and still have an extra space to the text? (escpecially the right half pie?)

Also is there a way to change only nuclear energy to a black text without changing the other white texts? Or do I need to create an extra node?
Can you actually change the position of the text inside the pie? E.g. I wand the RE from the left pie to be more relocated nearer the outside rim? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,arrows}


\begin {document}
\scalebox{0.7} {
\begin{tikzpicture}
%portion of pie
\pie[/tikz/nodes={text=black, font=\scriptsize},
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center, text=black, font=\scriptsize}, radius=5, rotate=-70, pos={6,0}, color={orange!50!white, blue!40!teal, cyan!80!white, cyan!30!white, red!80!black},before number=\phantom, after number=] %sum=39, blue!50!black
 {   0.5/\tikz [] {\draw[shorten <=0cm, thin, black] (0:-1) -- +(0:5mm) node [text=black, yshift=0.25cm, text width=1cm]{$0.01\%$ \\Geothermal};}, 
     8/\tikz [] {\draw[shorten <=0cm, thin, black] (0:-1) -- +(0:5mm) node [text=black,  yshift=0.25cm, text width=1cm]{$20\%$ \\Photovoltaik};}, 
     2.5/\tikz [] {\draw[shorten <=0cm, thin, black] (0:-1) -- +(0:5mm) node [text=black,  yshift=0.25cm, text width=1cm]{$7\%$ \\Hydropower};}, 
     20/\tikz [] {\draw[shorten <=0cm, thin, black] (0:-1) -- +(0:5mm) node [text=black,  yshift=-0.5cm, text width=1cm]{$52\%$ \\Wind energy};},
     8/\tikz [] {\draw[shorten <=0cm, thin, black] (0:-1) -- +(0:5mm) node [text=black, yshift=-0.5cm , text width=1.5cm]{$20\%$ \\Bio energy};}, 
  };
    

% %white pie for outer donut
\pie[radius=3.5, rotate=-70, pos={6,0}, white,
color={white},before number=\phantom, after number=,]
{39/}

%the pie
\pie[
/tikz/nodes={text=white, font=\scriptsize},
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center, text=black, font=\tiny},
 radius=4, pos={0,0}, rotate=-80,color={cyan!45!white, blue!60!black, red!40!orange, orange!40!white,
orange!50!yellow,orange!70!white}, sum=auto, text=inside, before number=\phantom, after number=,]
{
    45 /RE \\45\%, 
    7.5/\tikz [] {\draw[shorten <=3cm, thin, black] (0:-1) -- +(90:35mm) node [text=black, yshift=0.2cm]{$7.5\%$ hard coal};},
    16.1/natural gas \\16.1\%, 
    11.3/nuclear energy \\ 11.3\%, 
    0.7/\tikz [] {\draw[shorten <=4cm, thin, black] (0:-1)--+(224:45mm) node [text=black, yshift=-0.4cm, text width=1.5cm]{$0.7\%$ \\mineral oil products};},
    16.2/lignite \\16.2\%
    }

\path (0,0) node (Kreis) [draw, thick, circle, fill=white, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=2cm] {};

\path (Kreis)+(0.19,4) node(P1);
% \path (Pie.north)+(0.15,3) node(P2) {o};
\path (7.7,4.7) node (P2) [] {o};
\draw [dashed, black!40, very thick] (P1.center)--(P2.center);

\path (0.7,-4) node (P3) [] {o};
\path (P2)+(0,-9.4) node(P4) {};
\draw [dashed, black!40, very thick] (P3.center)--(P4.center)

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end {document}
```

[image: my pie so far]
[image: example pie chart]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.  That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.